# Como formatar código dentro de listas?

Tags: suporte, markdown

Estava agora há pouco tentando postar o seguinte trecho de código e não importa o que eu faça ele não mostra o código formatado devidamente.

**EDIT:**
Como pedido nos comentários, um screenshot:
[image: No SO-pt]

Agora o mesmo código sem nenhuma modificação, só que aqui no meta:
[image: Sem bug]

Espero que tenha dado pra entender.

PS: Não postei a pergunta, visto que implementei o que queria de uma forma diferente.

Comment: Como assim? vc quer ele 'funcione'? isso só funciona para javascript.

Comment: Não, quero formatar como código por causa de uma dúvida minha. Sabe essa caixa cinza com o código aí, não tá aparecendo direito nenhum no SO. Tentei dar Control+K, tentei clicar no botão de inserir código do editor, tentei colocar quatro espaços antes de cada linha e mesmo assim não deu.
Sei que parece bobo mas não foi, nem eu trocando de browser.

Comment: Na edição ele aparece normalmente, será que não foi outra coisa que você colocou perto dele que afetou? Poderia colocar a pergunta que ocorreu o problema?

Comment: Mostra onde você fez e não deu certo.

Comment: Faça o teste no sopt e tire um screenshot, assim todos podem ver o bug, que pela descrição não deu para entender.

Comment: O melhor não é tirar um SS, é mostrar onde está o problema. Ver o problema real é sempre melhor que uma foto.

Answer (score 8):

Quando quiser que o código seja considerado parte da lista, você precisa indentar com 8 espaços em vez de 4, e deixar uma linha vazia antes do código. Assim:

```
- item 1
        // código dentro do item 1, indentado com 8 espaços
- item 2
```

> **Resultado**
>
> - item 1
>
>   ```
>   // código dentro do item 1, indentado com 8 espaços
>   ```
> - item 2

Se quiser o código *depois* da lista, precisa haver algo entre a lista e o código. Caso não queira nada entre eles, use um comentário HTML, assim:

```
- item 1
- item 2

<!-- gambi -->

    // código fora da lista, indentado com 4 espaços
```

> **Resultado**
>
> - item 1
> - item 2
>
> ```
> // código fora da lista, indentado com 4 espaços
> ```